# How to use VueRouter on a smartphone's webview like WKWebView and Android WebView?

Tags: android, ios, vue.js, webview, vue-router

I cannot get the VueRouter to work with iOS's and Android's webview.

*(I am using `mode: 'history'` by the way)*

I already have successfully set up a webapp on an online server that is powered by Vue. The routing is taking care of by VueRouter. I am aware of the fact that 'normally' you would have to configure the server to redirect all requests to the index where your Vue app with the VueRouter is at.

But how would you accomplish such a thing in a phones webview. It confuses me since it is not a webserver.
Is it even possible in the first place.

I understand that you could consider this practice as not being the best one. But as we already have the entire app up and running on a webserver, it would be kind of waste of time to entirely revisit the app in NativeScript Vue for example just because of this problem.

Comment: Similar problem here, no clue either.

Comment: @FCR
Unfortunately I still don't know how such a thing can be accomplished.

But I think it is inherently impossible to do so.

The problem is not that the history mode doesn't work in a WebView (because that works just fine), but the main problem is that deeplinks from outside the app to a specific page won't work.
So I was thinking of a different approach:
Maybe you could catch a deeplink and send it back to the webview (by using https://github.com/wendux/DSBridge-Android for example). And then call the VueRouter to push that link in the view.